# 502 Badgateway in openshift scalable nodejs application

Tags: node.js, openshift

Created a sample scalable application using `nodejs` connected with mysql database in `openshift` . But I got `502 error bad gateway`.changed `#option httpchk GET` / in `haproxy`.

I have a database **testnodejs** having table `users(id int,name varchar)`;

my sample code 
index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function () {

            $.get('/users',data,function(data){

            });

        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Enter a username</h3>
<input id="user" type="text" />
<input id="submit" type="submit" />
<p id="output"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var express    = require('express'),
mysql      = require('mysql');

var ipaddr  = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";
var port    = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000;

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST,
    user     : process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME,
    password :process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD,
    port     :process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT,
    db       :"testnodejs"
});

app.use(express.bodyParser());
connection.connect();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/users', function(req, res){
connection.query("select * from users where name="+req.query["name"],
        function(err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            else {
                  res.send(result);
            }
        });
});
app.listen(port,ipaddr);
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode",port, ipaddr,     app.settings.env);
```